# Two static variables in same name(two different file) and extern one of them in any other file

Tags: c, static, extern

Declaring a variable as static in one file and do a extern declaration in another file - i thought this will give an error while linking as the extern variable will not be seen in any object, as the one which declared in other file was with qualifier static. But somehow the linker(renesas) didn't show any error and created executable.

If the above usecase was correct, what will happen if 2 variables be declared as static in 2 different files and another in another file with extern declaration? In this case 2 different memories will be created in 2 different objects, but which one of the variable will be linked for other variable was declared as extern in another file(as both the variable name are same)??

file1.c

```
static int test_var;
fn1()
{
   test_var = 1;
}
```

file2.c

```
static int test_var;
fn2()
{
   test_var = 2;
}
```

file3.c

```
extern int test_var;
fn3()
{
   int x;
   x = test_var;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3, sample code updated...

Comment: There's no definition for the `test_var` declared `extern` and there's no defintion for `main`. My linker flags both errors. Please show a _complete_ example.

Comment: That should give a linker error, and it does in my case (using clang on OS X): Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_test_var", referenced from: _fn3 in file3.o

Comment: There are a number of problems with that code. I count 7 warnings plus the linker errors (_test_var and _main) just with default warnings (clang/OSX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably in a way you have configured linker. If you are linking library everything will be OK here and `file3.o` module will have `test_var` reference as `UNDEFINED`.

If you're linking application from this 3 modules you will fail just because absence of `main()` routine definition and unresolved external will be considered even less evil. :-)

Just to check it please examine appropriate `*.o` modules symbol tables in your build process and then final result. Having such approach you will find the reason of your strange build behavior.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `file3.c` has **absolutely** no access to variable `test_var` in either `file1.c` or `file2.c`.  You should get a linking error if `test_var` is not declared within the scope of `file3.c`.

Answer (score 3):

In file1.c and file2.c, the keyword `static` means the variable `test_var` is **file scope**. That means this variable only accessible in the the file where it's declared.

In the file3.c, the keyword `extern` means the variable is declared in other file.

When the compiler compile the file3.c, it will mark the variable `test_var` is in other object file, and doesn't care where is it. So this file can be compiled, and no errors occurred.
But when the linker process this object files, it will found that no variable named as `test_var` can be link to file3, an error will be shown.

Comment: `static` means static linkage, not file scope, and the `extern` declaration in `file3.c` means that there's a definition for that variable somewhere else, the declaration is already there.

Comment: @effeffe I'm sorry for my mistake, I read the ISO document again, you are right.